# What is the expected behavior for strincmp?

Tags: c++, c, standards

I am wondering about the behavior of the generic implementation of the esoteric strincmp(). For example the implementation here for BSD: ftp://ftp.stu.edu.tw/BSD/FreeBSD/releases/i386/1.0-RELEASE/ports/elm/lib/strincmp.c.

```
printf( "%i\n", strcmp("cd", "cd") );
printf( "%i\n", stricmp("cd", "CD") );
printf( "%i\n", strincmp("cdefg", "CD", 2) );
printf( "%i\n", strincmp("cd", "CDe", 2) );
printf( "%i\n", strncmp("cd", "cde", 2) );
printf( "%i\n", strincmp("cd", "cde", 2) );
```

Testing this piece of code give the following output:

```
0
0
101
-101
0
-101
```

So as per the last two results, strncmp() and strincmp() does not give the same result for the same set of strings. Is this expected behavior, or is the implementation displayed on the URL broken?

Comment: Have you tried a more decent version instead of FreeBSD 1.0?

Comment: When I make the minor corrections to get the function to compile on a modern c++ compiler, it returns 0 in all cases, as expected. http://ideone.com/0uNLeN

Comment: That code was released in 1993.  Worrying about its corner-case behavior is a complete waste of time.

Comment: I am looking to do something like: strincmp(s, "ftp:", 4). What I really wanted to do is the equivalent to a case insensitive memcmp. . Is there a better way to do this with a standard C function? Or would you end up having to implement it as a non-standard function?

Comment: POSIX defined `strcasecmp` and `strncasecmp`, which you can use directly on bsd and linux with string.h (or strings.h).

Comment: The source code you provide for `strincmp` does not (incorrectly) return `-101` on your last line. So you are using another implementation in your test – a bad one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no expected behaviour; `strincmp` is not part of standard C++ (although `strncmp` is: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring).

You might want to ask about C, although I suspect it's not standardised there either.

Answer (score -3):

`strncmp()` compares characters of two strings, while `strcmp()` compares two strings. For further information see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

Comment: Notice the `i` in `strincmp`.